# Printout precision

Tags: output-formatting, date-and-time, output, number-representation, printing

For debugging, I print out the `SessionTime`. In the Notebook it looks like:

```
session time: 7.5156706
session time: 16.343847
session time: 33.0001902
session time: 49.5784192
session time: 77.5160721
session time: 105.813123
session time: 139.8601965
session time: 175.6729023
session time: 218.5325299
session time: 266.4234365
...
```

I also print it out to a text file, and it looks like:

```
session time: 7.5156706`8.327512730898745
session time: 16.343847`8.664899281569289
session time: 33.0001902`8.970061436482112
session time: 49.5784192`9.146837668738144
session time: 77.5160721`9.340936751494889
session time: 105.813123`9.47608452596886
session time: 139.8601965`9.597239127573262
session time: 175.6729023`9.696249769850814
session time: 218.5325299`9.791061086997049
session time: 266.4234365`9.877117419305542
...
```

I am quite confused about the backticks and the trailing numbers. AFAIK, the backtick is for precision, and often followed by an integer (and for some reason, then a period). If this is the case, then the Notebook and text file have different (`Print`) output formats. Where would I control that?

And what does that number mean??

I am further flummoxed by the monotonic increasing nature of those traling numbers.

Thanx.

Comment: Use ``Print[N[SessionTime[]]]`` or ``Print[NumberForm[SessionTime[]]]`` to remove/control the backticks. The number after the backticks denotes the [`Precision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html) of the number, as you have already figured it out yourself. The precision increases because the time elapsed increases, so you need more and more digits to represent it.

Comment: `SessionTime[]` seems to return ["arbitrary-precision numbers"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html)

Comment: I don't know why `SessionTime[]` uses arbitrary-precision numbers, but the increase in precision corresponds to the accuracy being "down to a granularity of at least `$TimeUnit` seconds" (per the docs). Examine `Accuracy /@ {<session times>}`.

Comment: I have no idea why this question was closed. I think the explanation of how to print arbitrary-precision numbers, and why the precision is monotonic increasing, would be helpful to others.